# How to get first element of list or `None` when list is empty?

Tags: python, list

I can do it like this but there has to be better way:

```py
arr = []
if len(arr) > 0:
    first_or_None = arr[0]
else:
    first_or_None = None
```

If I just do arr[0] I get IndexError.
Is there something where I can give default argument?

Comment: You can use: `first_or_none = arr[0] if arr else None` (`if arr` is just a shortened way to write `if len(arr) > 0`). Indexing the first item needs index `0`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the example you give is absolutely fine - it is very readable and would not suffer performance issues.

You could use the ternary operator python equivalent, if you really want it to be shorter code:

```
last_or_none = arr[0] if len(arr) > 0 else None
```

Comment: You could shorten `len(arr) > 0` to just `arr` because an empty array is False and non-empty True.

Comment: Ah even better - and something I didn't know - thanks :-)